# Error en swift NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

He migrado a `Swift 4` pero tengo el siguiente error que no consigo resolver:

> Cannont convert value of type '[String: AnyObject]' to expected aegument type '[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any]'

```
let encodedData = label.text!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let attributedOptions: [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType.rawValue: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html as AnyObject,
    NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.characterEncoding.rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue as AnyObject
]
let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
label.text = attributedString.string
```

El error me aparece aqui:

```
let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
```

En la variable: `attributedOptions`

Comment: creo no es necesario colocar el 'try' a menos que tengas un do {  "codigo"  } y demás,  por ejemplo yo tengo en un proyecto lo siguiente para poder asignar los atributos a un texto:   let atributeString = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "fuente", size: 20)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white].tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = atributeString.      tal vez si colocas un poco mas de codigo ver como lo tienes asignado te podamos ayudar de manera mas sencilla

Comment: al ser un objeto 'AnyObject', puede que al cambiarlo por 'Any' te solucione el problema

Answer (score 2):

En un Playground esto compila

```
let attributedOptions: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
    .documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
]
```